# Problem with async/await while using .forEach

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis

I'm making a simple `Redis'` request which is supposed to return all VALUES (not keys) in my database. The problem is that my function returns `tab` before the `.forEach` even starts. Why do I know that? My `console.log(tab)`'s result is printed before `console.log(cards)` for each iteration.
My interpreter also tells me inside the `.forEach` function that `"Promise returned from forEach argument is ignored"`.
What have I done wrong there? Why isn't async/await working inside `.forEach`?

```
router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const keys = await client.keys("*")
        //console.log(result)
        const tab = []
        await keys.forEach(async (key) => {
            const cards = await client.smembers(key)
            console.log(cards)
            tab.push(cards)
        })
        console.log(tab)
        return res.send(tab)
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err)
    }

});
```

Comment: `forEach` doesn't return a promise which is why you're getting that warning.

Comment: how about reduce or map? would it work with them? I'd like to avoid using loops

Comment: You'll still be iterating over an array with `map` or `reduce`. Maybe create an array of promises and await [`Promise.all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) instead.

Answer (score 5):

`forEach` is not meant to work with async functions. You can use a `for ... of` loop instead.

```
for(const key of keys){
    const cards = await client.smembers(key)
    console.log(cards)
    tab.push(cards)
}
```

Comment: how about reduce or map? would it work with them? I'd like to avoid using loops

Comment: @crazyfrog None of those work with `async` functions or `Promise`s. Sometimes a simple `for` loop is the easiest.

Comment: A little further explanation. While the `async foreach` runs in the original question, the observed outcome is because it's just doing *multiple async calls*. `async` will run in *parallels*  with the rest of the logic, which is why he sees that the `console.log(tab)` is returned *before* his `async foreach`. And as noted in this answer, `for of` is the solution to this problem.